# Form submit after preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to validate a form before it is submitted.  I've tried a couple of methods but I cant get the form to submit after preventDefault.  This is the code I have at the moment:

```
$('#formquote').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        console.log('here');
        validating = true;
        var tval = valText('input[name=contactname]');
        var pval = valPhone('input[name=telephone]');
        var eval = valEmail('input[name=email]');

        console.log(tval);
        console.log(pval);
        console.log(eval);

        if(tval && pval && eval){
            $("#formquote").unbind('submit');
            $("#formquote").submit();
        }
    });
```

The console logs you can see output as expected ('here', true, true, true respectively)
At the moment the form submits on the second time you press the button.  I've also tried the following suggestions to no avail:

```
-> $("#formquote").unbind('submit').submit(); //same result
-> $("#formquote").submit(); //by itself, infinite loop
-> $("#formquote")[0].submit(); //non function error
-> $('#formquote').unbind('submit', preventDefault); //'preventDefault' not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You shouldn’t use `eval` as variable name, it’s a native javascript method.

Comment: Can you check that the unbind is successful (ie. it doesn't call your function again). @David if it's not a reserved word you can use it.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Exactly, that’s why I made it into a comment, not an answer... and I wrote *shouldn’t* not *can’t*. I *can* write `Object=0`, but that doesn’t mean it’s a good idea...

Comment: @david: I noticed that when it turned blue on here haha, I renamed it and the issue remained

Comment: @David: okay, see your point there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of *always* preventing the form from submitting, doing your validation and submitting again if it passes, why don't you just prevent the submission when the validation fails? Something like this:

```
$('#formquote').submit(function (e) {
    validating = true;
    var tval = valText('input[name=contactname]');
    var pval = valPhone('input[name=telephone]');
    var eval = valEmail('input[name=email]');

    if (!(tval && pval && eval)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, I tried this too, e.preventDefault only works if its the first line in the function unfortunately

Comment: @user2902832 That's not true, unless one of the earlier lines of code is throwing an error causing the `e.preventDefault()` line to never be executed. Check your browser's developer tools for errors, fix those, and see what happens.

Comment: @user2902832 That doesn’t make sense, see this example: http://jsbin.com/eGEXOBe/1/edit

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I had changed eval to emval as I mentioned in another comment, but neglected to change this in the if statement.  This is now working, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I guess the accepted answer is the best way of doing this, but if, for some reason, you need to use `preventDefault()` first and then submit the form, this works for me:

```
$('#formquote').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Do validation stuff..
  // Then submit the form
  $(this).submit();
}
```