# jQuery preventDefault on first click only

Tags: jquery, click, preventdefault

I've been working on some jQuery for additional functionality on my clients shopping site.  I've been asked to create a Quick Buy button which sits on top of the products on category pages pulled in from Locatya - so far pretty straight forward.

For the desktop site the following code works flawlessly:

```
jQuery('#main_cat_prods').delegate('img', 'mouseenter', function(){
                var $skuID = this.src.match(/[a-z][a-z][a-z]\d\d\d\d\d/)[0];

            if ( !jQuery('#QuickBuyProdBox').length ) {
                jQuery(this).closest('.image').prepend('<div id="QuickBuyProdBox">');
            };
                jQuery("#QuickBuyProdBox").click(function(){
                    jQuery.event.trigger('lightbox', $skuID);
                });
                jQuery('.image, #QuickBuyProdBox').mouseleave(function(){
                    jQuery('#QuickBuyProdBox').remove();
            });
        });
```

Now, the difficulty comes when trying to develop a slightly different functionality on tablets; my client desires a single tap to prepend the QuickBuyProdBox and second tap to either:

Continue as normal to the product page IF clicked outside of the QuickBuyProdBox
Fire up the lightbox IF clicked on the QuickBuyProdBox.

I'm struggling first of all with:

Preventing default behavior of the img on the category page, I've tried preventDefault BUT this stops ALL click events on the main_cat_prods div.  I've also tried binding click for the first instance then unbinding it, this too doesn't seem to work:

```
jQuery("#main_cat_prods").bind('img', 'click', function( event) {
            if ( !jQuery('#QuickBuyProdBox').length ) {
                jQuery(this).closest('.image').prepend('<div id="QuickBuyProdBox">');
            };
            console.log("this works");
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).unbind( event );
        });
```

To summarize, the above code doesn't work.  I need to be able to:

Click on the main_cat_prods div and prevent default functionality while prepending QuickBuyProdBox.
Be able to click either main_cat_prods OR QuickBuyProdBox
Remove QuickBuyProdBox by clicking outside of (this) img OR clicking on another product.

Any suggestions?

Let me know if this doesn't make sense, I can attempt to reword it!

Cheers,
Myles

Comment: You could shorten your question.

Comment: try using a handler registered using `.one()` to prevent the default action - so that it will get executed only once

Comment: @ArunPJohny then the function wouldn't work. The OP wanted to just prevent default for first time only not it's function.

Comment: @C-link that is what I'm saying write a separate handler using `.one()` which will just have one line saying prevent the default action like `$(selector).one('click', function(e){e.preventDefault()})`

Comment: The main function which handles the code will have rest of the function - the prevent default code

Comment: @ArunPJohny  not that! inside function(e){//other codes also don't work}

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.data` to store a counter, then increment the counter on first click.
Inside the event handler, wrap the prevent default logic inside an `if` that checks the counter value before proceeding.

```
jQuery("#main_cat_prods img").data('clicked', 0);
jQuery("#main_cat_prods").bind('img', 'click', function( event) {
   var state = $(this).data('clicked') || 0;
   if(state === 0){
      // this will only happen the first time
      event.preventDefault();
      state++; // <-- we increment the state
      $(this).data('clicked', state);// <-- and store it back in data
   }
   // other code
});
```

This also has the added benefit of not requiring you to declare and global variables.

---

## EDIT

This may work better:

```
jQuery("#main_cat_prods img").data('clicked', 0);
jQuery("#main_cat_prods").bind('img', 'click', function( event) {
   var state = $(this).data('clicked') || 0;
   if(state === 0){
      // this will only happen the first time
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      state++; // <-- we increment the state
      $(this).data('clicked', state);// <-- and store it back in data
      return; // <-- we stop the rest of the handler from running
   }
   // other code
});
```

Comment: Oooo good stuff, nice answer - will test and get back to you.  Thanks @ekhaled.

Comment: to be fair.. you don't really have to increment it.. just set it to any other value apart from `0`

Comment: Argh!  This isn't working.  Again the preventDefault simply isn't firing... I think I need to use delegate in order for this to work - any way this can be worked in?

Comment: you may need both `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();`. Check the edit I just made, you may also need to short-out the handler function

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's still not playing though - not quite sure why.  I'll persist onwards and do some debugging!

Comment: would help if you could put up a reduced test case on jsFiddle

Comment: I know, I tried replicating this in a fiddle but I think part of the problem is the Locayta zone where the products are passed into the category pages.  I'm not entirely sure how useful a test would be, but I'll try to make one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.

Check here: [Form submit after preventDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810369/form-submit-after-preventdefault)

You just need to put an if statement around the preventDefault

Comment: How would this help?  If statements require two different variable conditions, what am I checking for here?  The only way I can relate to this answer is by somehow checking state to see if QuickBuyProdBox exists when main_cat_prods is clicked, and if it doesn't exist, then preventDefault